# Checking if a string is in a json file

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm currently working on a reputation command for marketplace servers, but whenever I run the command it doesn't find the author id and I'm not sure why.

```
@bot.command()
async def rep(ctx):
  with open('rep.json') as data_file:    
    data = json.load(data_file)
    print(data)
    if ctx.author.id not in data:
      new = {
        f"{ctx.author.id}": {
          "rep": 0
        }
      }

      with open('rep.json', 'w') as outfile:
        json.dump(new, outfile, sort_keys=True, indent=4)

      added = discord.Embed(title="Added to database", color=0x38dd22, description="You have been successfully added to our database, you may run this command again.")
      added.set_footer(text=f"Requested by {ctx.author} • {datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M%p')}", icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
      await ctx.send(embed=added)
    else:
      repu = json.loads(open("rep.json").read())[f"{ctx.author.id}"]["rep"]
      rep = discord.Embed(title="Reputation", color=0x38dd22, description=f"You currently have {repu} reputation.")
      rep.set_footer(text=f"Requested by {ctx.author} • {datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M%p')}", icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
      await ctx.send(embed=rep)
```

rep.json:

```
{
    "702221444796383454": {
        "rep": 0
    }
}
```

This is what the command returns:

```
{'702221444796383454': {'rep': 0}}
```

Thanks for any contribution.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what's going wrong - can you be more specific about where the problem is occurring?  And is all the code relevant to the issue?

Comment: The two look identical, please clarify your question. See [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since [`id`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.User.id) is of type `int`, you cannot compare it to a `str` object (which is the id in your json file).

Try transforming your `ctx.author.id` into `str` object, then you should be able to check if it's in the json file.